# Accessing the data of the selected item of a RadListView on doubleclick (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, telerik

I've got a question I've got a RadListView which I populate with a custommade list of ListViewDataItems (all under WinForms).

```
this.listView.Items.Add(new ListViewDataItem(myCustomId, new string[] { fileName, fileSizeInMB});
```

Then I added a doublclick event:

```
listView.DoubleClick += mainFormListView_DoubleClick;
```

And declared the event:

```
 void listView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
```

I then access the currently selected item with listView.Items[listView.SelectedIndex].

So far so good. 
But when I try to access the data I had put into that Item the problems start.
In total I want to get the "myCustomId" of the selected item when an item is doubleclicked,
but all I manage to get is a ListViewDataItem that holds not a single Data, and  only contains format properties.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong there or how exactly I can access the previously stored ID?

thanks

Comment: Currently (as I didnt find out how to access the data I need) it has no real body only a body I use for debugging to place a breakpoint there:
 var a = ((listView.Items[listView.SelectedIndex]) as ListViewDataItem);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created the `ListViewDataItem`, you set `myCustomId` as the `Text` property.

```
... new ListViewDataItem(myCustomId, ...
```

So see if the `Text` property on the `SelectedItem` has the value you're looking for.

```
private void radListView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myCustomId = radListView1.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

You may also want to test `radListView1.SelectedItem` to make sure it's not `null` before trying to access the `Text` property.

---

From your comment:

> the Debugger still says that neither function exists (only format functions when I get the mouse over "listView.SelectedItem" on the line var a = listView.SelectedItem

When a place a break point at runtime and inspect `SelectedItem`, I see both properties have a value:

[image]

Comment: so it functions (both .text and .value return the correct value). Interestingly the Debugger still says that neither function exists (only format functions when I get the mouse over "listView.SelectedItem" on the line var a = listView.SelectedItem. 

do you have any clue why that could be the case? (marking the answer as correct in the meantime as it functioned tnx).

Comment: Almost yes. When I inspect the element by moving the mouse over it and then seeing the "dropdownlist" with what properties,... it has neither the text nor the value properties show up AT ALL. it looks like as if the element does not have those (but I can use them successfully as in your solution above). Oh using VS2012 btw (don't know if that makes a difference in regards to that debugging issue.

Comment: Just saw your update. Exactly the mouseover that you show in the screenshot are what I would expect, but where on my PC it is so that neither value nor text show up in that list there.

Comment: No no base class shown interestingly when I compare your view and mine mine really shows only format functions of the dataelement 
 Like Backcolor1-4 and ActualSize,...